# Node.JS, Express & MongoDB Multiple Collections Async Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, collections

I'm using Node.JS, Express, MongoDB and EJS. I have a question regarding multiple MongoDB collections under one database, and calling them to use on the front-end. I have 2 collections, and after much research haven't found how to call more than one collection without errors.

This is my Controllers Folder:

```
const Post = require('../models/post');
const Slip = require('../models/slip');

module.exports.index = async (req, res) =>  {
const posts = await Post.find().sort({ createdAt: -1}).populate('author')
const slips = await Slip.find().sort({ createdAt: -1}).populate('author')
res.render("posts/index", {posts: posts, slips: slips});
  };
```

This is my Routes Folder:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const posts = require('../controllers/posts');
const slips = require('../controllers/slips');
const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const { isLoggedIn, isAuthor, validatePost, validateSlip } = 
require('../middleware');
const multer = require('multer');
const { storage } = require('../cloudinary');
const upload = multer({ storage });

router.route('/')
.get(isLoggedIn, catchAsync( posts.index))
```

This is my App.js File. I have all the relevant variables set up for this to work, just having trouble getting both Posts and Slips show on the index page

```
app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
```

This is my index.ejs file:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <%- include("../layouts/leftsidenewsevents") %>
   <div id="main">
    <div id="feedheading" class="d-flex justify-content-between">
     <h3>Posts</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
    <% for (let post of posts ){%>


     <div class="container-fluid shadow" id="firstpost">
      <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="postuserdetails">
        <div class="postuserdetails">
          <% post.author.images.forEach((img, i) => {  %>
          <div class="carousel-item <%= i === 0 ? 'active' : ''%>">
              <img id="profilepic" src="<%= img.url%>" alt="profilepicture" class="rounded-circle">
          </div>
          <% }) %>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="postuserdetails">
          <div class="cap">
            <h5><%= post.author.username%></h5>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p id="status">Gold</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p id="postdate"><%= post.createdAt%></p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p id="postdate">Follow</p></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-flex" id="currentrating2"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p> 4.5</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex" id="postdescription">
        <p id="postwords"><%= post.snippet %></p>
      </div>

    <hr id="hrfull">

      <div id="A<%= post._id.toString()%>" class="carousel slide"data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000000">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
      <% post.images.forEach((img, i) => {  %>
      <div class="carousel-item <%= i === 0 ? 'active' : ''%>">
          <img src="<%= img.url%>" class="d-block" alt="">
      </div>
      <% }) %>
        </div>
         <% if(post.images.length > 1) {%>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#A<%=post._id.toString()%>" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#A<%=post._id.toString()%>" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>

      </div>
       <% } %>

    <hr id="hrfull">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="commentpostcontainer">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between m-0 p-0 "id="currentrating">
          <div class="rating">
            <h7>Rating</h7>
          </div>
         <div class="rating">
           <div class="rating">
            <input name="stars" id="e5" type="radio"></a><label for="e5"><i class="far fa-star"></i></label>
                <input name="stars" id="e4" type="radio"></a><label for="e4"><i class="far fa-star"></i></label>
                <input name="stars" id="e3" type="radio"></a><label for="e3"><i class="far fa-star"></i></label>
                <input name="stars" id="e2" type="radio"></a><label for="e2"><i class="far fa-star"></i></label>
                <input name="stars" id="e1" type="radio"></a><label for="e1"><i class="far fa-star"></i></label>
           </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <hr id="hrfull">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="commentpostcontainer">
        <div id="viewcommentsbox" class="float-left">
                <a class="" href="/posts/<%=post._id%>">View Comments</a>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
          <% currentUser.images.forEach((img, i) => {  %>
            <img id="profilepiccomments" src="<%= img.url%>" alt="profile picture" class="rounded-circle m-1 p-1">
          <% }) %>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a comment..." aria-label="Recipient's username"aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="commentbtn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% }%>
    <div id="deadspace"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    const posts = { features: <%- JSON.stringify(posts) %>}
    </script>
```

My Models Folder (both Post Models and Slips Model is same criteria):

```
Post Model:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Review = require('./review')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const ImageSchema = new Schema({
url: String,
filename: String
});

const opts = { toJSON: { virtuals: true } };

const Postschema = new Schema({
snippet: String,
images: [ImageSchema],
betAmount: Number,
odds: Number,
value: String,
author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
reviews: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Review'
    }
]
}, { timestamps: true },
opts);

module.exports = mongoose.model('post', Postschema);1

Slip Model:

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Review = require('./review')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const ImageSchema = new Schema({
url: String,
filename: String
});



const opts = { toJSON: { virtuals: true } };



const Slipschema = new Schema({
snippet: String,
images: [ImageSchema],
betAmount: Number,
odds: Number,
value: String,
author: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
reviews: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Review'
    }
]
}, { timestamps: true },
opts);


module.exports = mongoose.model('slip', Slipschema);
```

Comment: What's the error your getting ? the code has issues. i can find a problem with below line 

res.render("posts/index", {posts: posts, slips, slips});

Should be 
res.render("posts/index", {posts: posts, slips: slips});

Comment: only one collection is being displayed. which ever is first. for example if 'res.render("posts/index", {posts: posts, slips, slips});' - Posts collection will be displayed; OR 'res.render("posts/index", {slips, slips, posts: posts});' - Slips will be displayed.

Comment: My mistake may be in the <% for (let post of posts ){%> I have in my EJS file. But I am unsure which variables to have here to capture the two different collections from the database. @VeerR